# How to move a Json Array inside a Json Object?

Tags: javascript, json

I contain the following JSON Returned:

```
"description": {
    "tags": [
      "person",
      "indoor",
      "clothing",
      "woman",
      "posing",
      "hair",
      "wearing",
      "young",
      "holding",
      "white",
      "shirt",
      "smiling",
      "black",
      "camera",
      "red",
      "sitting",
      "standing",
      "yellow",
      "blue",
      "room"
    ],
    "captions": [
      {
        "text": "Angelina Jolie wearing a white shirt and black hair",
        "confidence": 0.8567016879020947
      }
    ]
  },
```

I already tried to do it in several ways, including this one below and I do not get any results:

```
function gerarLegenda(obj){
   for(c in obj.description.captions){
  document.getElementById("legenda-collection").innerHTML += '<a href="#!" class="collection-item"><span class="badge red white-text">'+ obj.description[c].captions[c].confidence +" %"+'</span> <span class="new badge red"></span>'+ obj.description[c].captions[c].text +'</a>';
   }
}
```

I'm doing this to display the information for the separate "captions" and tags.

Comment: Are you sure it's parsed? Make sure it's an object and not a string, as you seem to indicate.

Answer (score 1):

`obj.description[c].captions[c].confidence` should be `obj.description.captions[c].confidence`

**EDIT:**
This may potentially be easier to read

```
function gerarLegenda(obj) {
    var legend = document.getElementById("legenda-collection");
    obj.description.captions.forEach(function(caption) {
      legend.innerHTML += '<a href="#!" class="collection-item"><span class="badge red white-text">'+ caption.confidence +" %"+'</span> <span class="new badge red"></span>'+ caption.text +'</a>';        
    });
}
```

Note that this code of yours leads to [layout thrashing](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), especially if the `captions` array is large. Rather build up a string of anchor tags, then write once to the HTML element of your choice.

Answer (score -1):

In the context of `for (c in obj.description.captions)`, `c` is already an object like this:

```
 {
   "text": "Angelina Jolie wearing a white shirt and black hair",
   "confidence": 0.8567016879020947
 }
```

So you only need to use `c`. `c.text` and `c.confidence`.

```js
function gerarLegenda(obj){
  for(c in obj.description.captions){
    document.getElementById("legenda-collection").innerHTML += '<a href="#!" class="collection-item"><span class="badge red white-text">' + c.confidence +" %"+'</span> <span class="new badge red"></span>'+ c.text +'</a>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Needs to be [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) in order to do `c.text` and `c.confidence`. Otherwise needs to be `obj.description.captions[c].text` and `obj.description.captions[c].confidence`.

Comment: `captions` is an array, so, why use `for...in`. `forEach` will work perfectly.

Comment: Was just advising that your answer is incorrect.